# Universal library for C++ strings

Tags: c++, string, unicode, ascii

Please recommend me universal library for C++ strings. I want to manipulate ascii text and unicode text in one build without making two versions of builds for std::string/char and for std::wstring/wchar; Also I want to convert them to each other (where it is possible);

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 5):

Just use `std::wstring`, then. ASCII is a perfect subset of Unicode (and ISO 8859-1 Latin-1 sits in the middle). ASCII 0x5D is U+005D etcetera.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that because you're talking about using `wchar_t` for Unicode that we're talking about a Windows box. I wouldn't bother with making two separate builds -- nobody bothers supporting the ANSI only versions of Windows anymore. If you MUST do that, just use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` (i.e. `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring`) and go from there.

Converting between the two is going to be locale specific -- i.e., you have to know which particular narrow character codepage to which you wish to convert before going and doing the actual conversion. Win32 provides `WideCharToMultiByte` and `MultiByteToWideChar` to accomplish these kinds of conversions.

Comment: wchar_t is a standard C type.  It doesn't necessarily mean Windows.

Comment: @JeremyP: Yes, but it's not typically used for Unicode anywhere but Windows. POSIX boxes typically use `char *` and UTF-8 instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert between UTF8 string and UTF16 wstring on Windows, you can use thin wrappers around WideCharToMultiByte and MultiByteToWideChar WIN32 API functions:

```
std::string wstring_to_string(const std::wstring& in)
{
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, in.c_str(), -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::vector<char> buf(len);

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, in.c_str(), -1, &buf[0], len, 0, 0);
    return std::string(buf.begin(), buf.end());
}

std::wstring string_to_wstring(const std::string& in)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    std::vector<wchar_t> buf(len);

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in.c_str(), -1, &buf[0], len);
    return std::wstring(buf.begin(), buf.end());
}
```

Comment: That code is not exception safe. If construction of the `string` / `wstring` fails, `buffer` is leaked. Use a `vector` instead (i.e. https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/pevfind/src/9a50b0c6776b/pevFind/utility.cpp#cl-82 ) (BTW ignore the rest of the code in that file -- it's pretty bad)

Comment: Thanks Billy, I have updated the code snippet to use std::vector for basic exception safety as you pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing cross-platform coding you could use  Qt4's [QString](http://doc.trolltech.com/qstring.html) / [QByteArray](http://doc.trolltech.com/qbytearray.html).

Comment: The QT's API looks very decent, do you know if it can be used separately without the whole lib?

Comment: @user1633272 yeah they can, the library is split into smaller chunks, most of the base is in QtCore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a library, but I'd like to point out you can always go from one to another, e.g.:

```
string s;
foo(s.c_str());
```

or

```
char *s;
foo(string(s));
```

Just be careful going from `wstring` to `char*` or `string` as you will have to perform some conversion.

Comment: Err... no, attempting to just take the buffer returned by `std::wstring::c_str()` is not going to work for anybody expecting a `char *`. You're going to have to do some form of conversion.

Comment: @Billy As I mentioned in my last line. :)

Comment: No -- it's worse than "just loosing unicode support" -- it will appear as an empty string to anybody not expecting wide character strings.

Comment: @Billy Fair point, edited in.

Comment: +1 for edit (in 15 characters too)

Answer (score 1):

[Boost String Algorithms Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) can be used for many text operations on both string and wstring.

Answer (score 1):

In Java and Objective-C (and C#?) the strategy is to encode everything internally as UTF-16 and use conversions when getting strings from or sending strings to external entities (e.g. files, the UI).  For sanity, you should probably do the same thing.  Hold everything internally as UTF-16 (you need 16 bits per character for this).  Use string libraries to convert between UTF-16 and external representations. In C I can think of three off the top of my head

- [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)
- [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)
- [CFLite](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/) (quite limited set of supported encodings).

In C++, I don't know of any libraries.  Your OS platform may also contain its own library to do the conversion.

Unless you know you will always be dealing with straight ASCII or ISO-8859-1 you should always use a library to do conversions rather than rolling your own because the gotchas are many and varied.